# CSS Grid minmax - need verification, please

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm trying the following grid layout which I need to be responsive. The width of the contained text must be 890 pixels maximum and resized to fit on mobile phones.

I did some experiments and with "minmax(auto, 890px)" seems to work - tested on Chrome developer tool, Microsoft Edge and Firefox.

However I doubt this is the proper way to do it, as I have not found any clue anywhere. Am I doing it right? There's a better and proper way to achieve this?

CSS

```
article {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 0px minmax(auto, 890px) 0px 1fr 1fr;
    margin: 15vh 0 15vh 0 /* margin top and bottom of whole content */
}

article > * {
    grid-column: 4;
}

article > figure {
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
    margin: 20px 0;
}

.container {
    width: 85%;
    max-width: 1400px;
    margin: 0 auto
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">

<article>


        <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>

        <figure>
            <img src="https://mave.me/img/projects/full_placeholder.png">
        </figure>

        <h2>More lorem ipsum</h2>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>

</article>

</div>
```

Comment: `fit-content(890px)` would be what you need i think

Answer (score 0):

The proper way is to use breakpoints and write dedicated css for different breakpoints. See [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_media_query_breakpoints.asp) for reference.
For article you could also set width: 100% or whatever and max-width: 890px to have the width automatically resized.

Comment: Yes, I know about breakpoints. But shouldn't we always aim for the most up-to-date css - maybe even with a fallback? Css grid is defined as a solution to breakpoints in modern css - not by me, but by sources like csstricks etc. But forgive me if I'm wrong, I'm quite ignorant on the subject